# how to assign the ajax return data to my variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to do this but unable to set the return data of ajax call to my variable $variable. remember i am working in a js file

```
var variable = {}

$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: baseurl + 'port/skills',
        context: document.body,
        error: function (data, transport) {
            alert("Sorry, the operation is failed.");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //var countries=data;
            $("variable").val(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `variable` doesn't seem to be a valid selector, and it's quotes as a string inside `$()`

Comment: Is data is of Array type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `variable = data;` instead of `$("variable").val(data);`

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are doing something wrong.

Try this `variable = data;` instead of using `$("variable").val(data);`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: baseurl + 'port/skills',
        context: document.body,
        error: function (data, transport) {
            alert("Sorry, the operation is failed.");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //var countries=data;
            variable = data;
        }
    });
});
```

[See Working Example in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6bJ2/584/)

**[Variable in Javascript](http://www.wikihow.com/Declare-a-Variable-in-Javascript)**

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
    var variable = {}

$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: baseurl + 'port/skills',
        context: document.body,
        error: function (data, transport) {
            alert("Sorry, the operation is failed.");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //var countries=data;
            variable = data;
        }
    });
});
```